# Azure ARM - DSC VM configuration

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell, azure-automation, dsc

I would like to configure my VMs using ARM template and DSC. I prepared simple DCS script in powershell, base on that using powershell command created .zip file. mentioned .zip file uploaded to storage account container. Now I want to use this .zip file to made configuration changes on my test VMs, below my ARM template. I am receiving error message `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : 10:12:09 AM - VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'dscExtension'. Error message: "The DSC Extension failed to execute: Error downloading 
https://storageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/containerName/test.zip after 2 attempts: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>ResourceNotFound</Code><Message>The specified resource 
does not exist.`

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "vmName": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1,
            "metadata": {
                "description": "List of virtual machines to be reconfigured, if using multiple VMs, make their names comma separate. E.g. VM01, VM02, VM03."
            },
            "defaultValue": "VM1,VM2"
        },
        "Location": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Location of the VM"
            },
            "defaultvalue": "WestEurope"
        },
        "functionName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Specify the function name"
            },
            "defaultvalue": "test.ps1\\testConfigurationName"
        },
        "storageAccountName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Specify the Storage Account name, Storage Account where DCS .zip module is located"
            }
        },
        "setupScriptContainerName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Specify the Storage Account container name, container where DCS .zip module is located"
            }
        },
        "DSCSetupArchiveFileName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Specify the Storage Account container name, container where DCS .zip module is located"
            },
            "defaultvalue": "test.zip"
        },
        "nodeConfigurationName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the node configuration, on the Azure Automation DSC pull server, that this node will be configured as"
            },
            "defaultValue": "testConfigurationName.localhost"
        },
        "registrationKey": {
            "type": "securestring",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Registration key to use to onboard to the Azure Automation DSC pull/reporting server"
            },
            "defaultValue": "AutomationAccountPrimaryKey"
        },
        "registrationUrl": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Registration url of the Azure Automation DSC pull/reporting server"
            },
            "defaultValue": AutomationAccountRegistrationURL"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "vmListArray": "[split(parameters('vmName'),',')]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
            "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
            "name": "[concat(trim(variables('vmListArray')[copyIndex()]),'/dscExtension')]",
            "copy": {
                "name": "ExtentionLooptoAllVMs",
                "count": "[length(variables('vmListArray'))]"
            },
            "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
            "properties": {
                "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
                "publisher": "Microsoft.Powershell",
                "type": "DSC",
                "typeHandlerVersion": "2.19",
                "protectedSettings": {
                    "Items": {
                        "registrationKeyPrivate": "[parameters('registrationKey')]"
                    }
                },
                "settings": {
                    "ModulesUrl": "[concat('https://',parameters('storageAccountName'),'.blob.core.windows.net/',parameters('setupScriptContainerName'),'/',parameters('DSCSetupArchiveFileName'))]",
                    "ConfigurationFunction": "[parameters('functionName')]",
                    "Properties": [
                        {
                            "Name": "RegistrationKey",
                            "Value": {
                                "UserName": "PLACEHOLDER_DONOTUSE",
                                "Password": "PrivateSettingsRef:registrationKeyPrivate"
                            },
                            "TypeName": "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "RegistrationUrl",
                            "Value": "[parameters('registrationUrl')]",
                            "TypeName": "System.String"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "NodeConfigurationName",
                            "Value": "[parameters('nodeConfigurationName')]",
                            "TypeName": "System.String"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Updated version:

```
"resources": [
      {
          "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
          "apiVersion": "2018-10-01",
          "name": "[concat(trim(variables('vmListArray')[copyIndex()]),'/dscExtension')]",
          "copy": {
              "name": "ExtentionLooptoAllVMs",
              "count": "[length(variables('vmListArray'))]"
          },
          "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
          "properties": {
              "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
              "publisher": "Microsoft.Powershell",
              "type": "DSC",
              "typeHandlerVersion": "2.9",
              "protectedSettings": {
                  "Items": {
                      "registrationKeyPrivate": "[parameters('registrationKey')]"
                  }
              },
              "settings": {
                  "configuration": {
                      "url": "[concat('https://',parameters('storageAccountName'),'.blob.core.windows.net/',parameters('setupScriptContainerName'),'/',parameters('DSCSetupArchiveFileName'))]",
                      "script": "[parameters('scriptName')]",
                      "function": "[parameters('functionName')]"
                  },
                  "Properties": [
                      {
                          "Name": "RegistrationKey",
                          "Value": {
                              "UserName": "PLACEHOLDER_DONOTUSE",
                              "Password": "PrivateSettingsRef:registrationKeyPrivate"
                          },
                          "TypeName": "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential"
                      },
                      {
                          "Name": "RegistrationUrl",
                          "Value": "[parameters('registrationUrl')]",
                          "TypeName": "System.String"
                      },
                      {
                          "Name": "NodeConfigurationName",
                          "Value": "[parameters('nodeConfigurationName')]",
                          "TypeName": "System.String"
                      },
                      {
                          "Name": "ConfigurationMode",
                          "Value": "[parameters('configurationMode')]",
                          "TypeName": "System.String"
                      },
                      {
                          "Name": "ConfigurationModeFrequencyMins",
                          "Value": "[parameters('configurationModeFrequencyMins')]",
                          "TypeName": "System.Int32"
                      },
                      {
                          "Name": "RefreshFrequencyMins",
                          "Value": "[parameters('refreshFrequencyMins')]",
                          "TypeName": "System.Int32"
                      },
                      {
                          "Name": "RebootNodeIfNeeded",
                          "Value": "[parameters('rebootNodeIfNeeded')]",
                          "TypeName": "System.Boolean"
                      },
                      {
                          "Name": "ActionAfterReboot",
                          "Value": "[parameters('actionAfterReboot')]",
                          "TypeName": "System.String"
                      },
                      {
                          "Name": "AllowModuleOverwrite",
                          "Value": "[parameters('allowModuleOverwrite')]",
                          "TypeName": "System.Boolean"
                      }
                  ]
              }
          }
      }
  ]
```

DSC part:

```
Configuration SetRegistryxxx {


    Node 'localhost' {
         Registry configxxx {
                Ensure = "Present"
                Key = "HKLM:\xx"
                ValueName = "xx"
                ValueData = "http://0.0.0.0:xxx
                ValueType = "String"
        }
        Registry configxxx {
                Ensure = "Present"
                Key = "HKLM:\xx"
                ValueName = "xx"
                ValueData = "http://0.0.0.0:xx"
                ValueType = "String"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error, you can not download the zip file from the Azure blob storage account you use. Please create a sas token for the blob or [set the blob access level to `Public`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-access-to-resources?tabs=dotnet).

For example

```
 "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('vmName'),'/Microsoft.Powershell.DSC')]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Powershell",
        "type": "DSC",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "2.19",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "protectedSettings": {
          "Items": {
            "registrationKeyPrivate": "[parameters('registrationKey')]"
          }
        },
        "settings": {
          "ModulesUrl": "<the url of you azure blob>",
          "SasToken": "<the sas token for the blob>",
          "ConfigurationFunction": "[parameters('configurationFunction')]",
        ...
}
]
```

For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/dsc-template#update-from-a-previous-format) and the [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/077f36e38ada0d9b4fa96efbe0d98ddb7b290001/dsc-extension-azure-automation-pullserver/azuredeploy.json#L125)

Comment: Hi Jim, in fack my blob is private, I used SAS token generated in the portal, added SAS token property to the ARM template. I also tried to use old style archieved file format -  reg-dsc-config.ps1.zip, but still receiving the same error message I mentioned earlier, I dont now what is wrong, I checked this ARM and the structure is almost the same as in link you pasted - "template". I used all properties apart from "timestamp". In `"ModulesUrl":` I am using standard https:// link format not the blob SAS url link style.

Comment: I also tried this - in the field `"ModulesUrl"` I pasted blob SAS url, and in a result receive different error message: `"message": "VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'dscExtension'. Error message: \"The DSC Extension received an incorrect input: A parameter  
cannot be found that matches parameter name 'NodeConfigurationName'.\r\n\r\nAnother common error is to specify parameters of type PSCredential without an explicit 
type.`

Comment: @tester81 Regarding the issue, please refer to https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/24784

Comment: Hi Jim, I totally rebuild my ARM template. Pasted Resources section as an "Updated version" in my code section. ARM template completes without any errors, ARM installs DSC extension on VMs, ARM adds Nodes to the AutomationAccount\DSC\Nodes section. Problem is that on VMs there is no change, my DSC/ps1 script in .zip format didnt make any modifications on VMs.

Comment: @tester81 Please check if you create a right zip file : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/dsc-overview#azure-portal-functionality. Besides, you can check you logs. The log location is `C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\{Extension_Name}\{Extension_Version}`. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/dsc-windows#troubleshoot-and-support

Comment: Hi Jim, I've updated my post, added my DSC code, it works, I tested it directly on e VM. I used command --> Publish-AzVMDscConfiguration .\test01.ps1 -OutputArchivePath '.\test01.zip'. I suppose, the .zip file is ok, my test01.zip file is stored in the private container. Problem is that Configuration is not added to the Automation Account/DSC/Configurations tab, i dont see it in the portal, and Configuration is not applied on VMs. I added configuration manually in the portal (as a ps1 file) and it works, but from ARM there is still problem. Do you have any ideas why it doesnt work?

Comment: @tester81 According to my test, it is ok for me. Please refer to the document: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/troubleshooting-azure-virtual-machine-dsc-extension/ to solve it. Besides, if you still have the issue. I suggest you raise a support ticket on Azure Portal : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request